# How to loop the names of a list?

Tags: r

```
target<-data.frame(q01=1,q03=1:10)
total<-list(t1=c('q02','q05'),t2=c('q01','q04'),t3=c('q03','q06'))

for(m in colnames(target)){
  for(j in total){
    print(names(j))
  }
}
```

When I run above script,result is:

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

My expect result is:

```
t1
t2
t3
t1
t2
t3
```

I cannot find out the problem,`names(j)` seemed not workable in loop.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the index of the list instead of the entire list :

```
for(m in colnames(target)){
   for(j in seq_along(total)) {
     print(names(total)[j])
   }
}

#[1] "t1"
#[1] "t2"
#[1] "t3"
#[1] "t1"
#[1] "t2"
#[1] "t3"
```

Comment: Any advantage of using `seq_along` instead of `length`?

Comment: To create sequence using `length` you need to do `1:length(total)`, `seq_along` does it directly.